# Can I call method in each base recursively without manually typing base::Method()?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The content

- The question
- Example
- Why do I need it

Hi.

### The question

I am facing a problem. I have a class **A** that has a base **B** (is polymorphic). In **B** class is method Print(), wich is virtual. In **A** class is also Print(). virtual. 
Lets say I am given an A type object (or pointer), stored in B variable

```
B * object = new A();
```

And by calling

```
object->Print();
```

It calls the method in A class, but I also want it to call method in B class.
Technically
**I want to call the method for each child until i reach class that has no child**
This can be done as follows:

### Example

```
class A
{
   public:
      virtual void Print() const override
      {
          cout << "A" << endl;
      }
};
class B : public A
{
   public:
      virtual void Print() const override
      {
         cout << "B" << endl;
         A::Print();     // i do not want to call it here...
      }
};
```

The problem is that I do want not to be forced to call the

```
A::Print();
```

### Why

Yes, you might be asking, what is the deal...
I have very long inheritance chain. (lets say that there are like 15 - 20 classes in the inheritance chain). 
In a game, each one does some little thing.

Lets say

```
 class GameObject
    {
       public:
          virtual void Update() const
          {
              //updates position, recounts it towards screen
          }
    };
    class Character : public GameObject
    {
       public:
          virtual void Update() const override
          {
             // Updates lives, movement
          }
    };
    class Warrior : public Character
    {
       public:
          virtual void Update() const override
          {
             // Updates armor, specific stuff
          }
    };
```

Now this example is very simplified. Problem is, that if i forget to add a call base::Update() Then I am worndering why does it not work. Looking for such a misstake is hard. I mean, if there any way around it?

Thank you very much indeed for any responses.

Have a nice day

Comment: and what happens if someone else does not want to do that? Or have a conditional when to call this daisy chain?

Comment: Your class hierarchy and the way classes call each other should be better defined IMO. Don't follow inheritance concepts but fonctionality. If a GameObject needs to do several different things, make a function for each, having non-virtual functions call virtuals in a specific order.    
For example, you could have a base `Update()` in `GameObject` that calls non-virtual engine stuff, and then calls virtual `Move`, `Think` etc. which only do something if you derived and implemented them.

Comment: Please, could the down-voter explain the reason of the down vote? IMHO the question is clear and well explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If indeed every class must call the base function, one way to ensure the functionality is enforced is to use the [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

```
class GameObject
{

   public:
      void Updater()
      {
         Update();  // this is a virtual call
         GameObject::Update(); // now call base 
      }

      virtual void Update() const
      {
      }
};

class Character : public GameObject
{
   public:
      virtual void Update() const override
      {
         // Updates lives, movement
      }
};

class Warrior : public Character
{
   public:
      virtual void Update() const override
      {
         // Updates armor, specific stuff
      }
};

class Character : public GameObject
{
   public:
      virtual void Update() const override
      {
         // Updates lives, movement
      }
};

class Warrior : public Character
{
   public:
      virtual void Update() const override
      {
         // Updates armor, specific stuff
      }
};
```

Then always call `YourObject::Updater();` instead of `YourObject::Update()`.  The `Updater` function will call your object's `Update` function, and then return and call the base class `Update`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that in that way my code would grow more and get bit more confusing for me. But thank you very much :] I guess there is no way to automatically do it. :]

Comment: It won't get confusing if you study the various design patterns.  Basically you want to make sure that your derived classes, when Update() is called, to follow a specific set of rules (what must be called before Update(), after Update(), etc.).  One way to enforce these rules is to have the base class define the rules, and have the derived classes override the parts that are customized.  Then the base class calls a function that processes each step, where some of these steps are customized by the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

There was once a proposal to get all the bases of a given type ([N2965](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html)) which gcc actually implemented in `<tr2/type_traits>`. So, if portability is not a concern and you happen to be using gcc, you can write a catch-all like so:

```
struct A { 
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void print() { print_all(*this); }    
    void print_one() { std::cout << "A\n"; }

protected:
    template <class T>
    void print_all(T& object) {
        object.print_one();
        print_all(object, typename std::tr2::bases<T>::type{});
    }   

    template <class T, class... Bases>
    void print_all(T& object, std::tr2::__reflection_typelist<Bases...> ) { 
        using swallow = int[];
        (void)swallow{0,
            (static_cast<Bases&>(object).print_one(), 0)...
        };
    }   
};
```

This splits up `print()`, which prints everything, and `print_one()` which just prints the one specific type. You just have your `print()` call `print_all()` with itself:

```
struct B : A { 
    void print() override { print_all(*this); }
    void print_one() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C : B { 
    void print() override { print_all(*this); }
    void print_one() { std::cout << "C\n"; }
};
```

Otherwise, you'll have to wait for one of the reflection proposals to get adopted.